# Welche Dinge "stellt" man auf den Tisch? Welche "legt" man?

Tags: difference, usage

Aus [DW - Learn German](https://www.facebook.com/dw.learngerman/posts/10152857191962394):

> Die Teller habe ich schon auf den Tisch ___, aber das Besteck fehlt noch.
>
> a) gestellt b) gelegt
>
> Lösung: a)
>
> Die Teller habe ich schon auf den Tisch GESTELLT, aber das Besteck fehlt noch.
>
> **Man "legt" Servietten und Besteck auf den Tisch. Gläser und Teller "stellt" man.**

Den fetten Satz kann ich nicht ganz nachvollziehen. Ich hatte den Eindruck, dass man "stellen" für etwas Vertikales verwenden, "legen" für etwas Horizontales. Aber hier wird behauptet, dass man Teller stellt, obwohl sie horizontal sind.

Welche Dinge "stellt" man auf den Tisch? Welche "legt" man? Was sind die Kriterien?

Comment: Weil ich dafür keinen Nachweis habe, nur als Kommentar. Obwohl Teller flach sind, zeigt die "Öffnung" nach oben, deshalb kann man sie analog zu Gläsern und Schüsseln als vertikale Objekte wahrnehmen.

Comment: Dem würde ich zustimmen. Ein Teller ist ja, obwohl er flach ist, ein stabiles Gefäß, genau wie eine Schüssel oder ein Glas. Außerdem ist in der Regel die Fläche, mit der der Teller den Tisch berührt, kleiner als die Fläche der Oberseite.

Comment: Ich denke, ich würde es nicht als falsch empfinden, wenn jemand einen Teller auf den Tisch legt. Anders bei einem Glas, weil das dann nicht richtig angerichtet ist.

Comment: @Œlrim Der Ansatz ist nicht schlecht, aber warum *stelle* ich ein Paket auf dem Tisch ab, unabhängig davon, welche Seite ich verwende (und gegenüberliegende Seiten sind gleich groß).

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22264/der-fu%C3%9Fball-steht-oder-liegt

Comment: @Em1: "Ich lege das Paket auf den Tisch" ist doch auch korrekt oder? Das Paket ist in *meisten Fällen" würfelartig, es spielt also keine Rolle...

Comment: @BarthZalewski Es kommt hier auf die Paketgröße an. Ein großes, schwere Paket wird man abstellen. Ein kleines, leichtes Paket(chen) legt man ab. Die Form ist unerheblich.

Comment: Ich denke, man /stellt/ etwas hin, wenn es eine "vorgesehene Aufstellfläche" (ein Bein, Fuss, oder gemeinhin ein "unten") am Objekt gibt und man diese nutzt. Vgl ein Weinglas: Steht es auf dem Fuss, "stellt" man es hin. Nutzt man den Fuss nicht, "legt" man es.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beim *Stellen* positionierst du ein Objekt gemäß einer vorgesehenen Ausrichtung.

So kann man ein Buch gleichermaßen in einem Regal ablegen, als auch stellen, je nachdem ob man es *flach* "ablegt" (mit der Vorderseite nach oben oder unten) oder *aufrecht* (mit dem Rücken in den Raum hinein) "aufstellt".

Es gibt Dinge, für die keine übliche "Aufstell"-Position existiert, oder die durch ihre Art nicht aufstellbar sind, wie etwa ein Blatt Papier (sehr flach, praktisch zweidimensional) oder eine Orange (rund, es gibt kein hinten, vorn, oben, unten). Diese lassen sich ablegen, aber nicht aufstellen.

Generell sind Dinge aber nur dann **auf**gestellt, wenn ihre Position **auf**recht ist. So ist ein Smartphone nicht aufgestellt, wenn es auf dem Tisch liegt, obwohl man einfach auf den Bildschirm schauen kann. Da es aber offensichtlich **liegt,** ist es nicht aufgestellt, sondern abgelegt.
Nehmen wir jedoch einmal an, dass solch ein Smartphone kleine Noppen auf der Rückseite hat. In diesem Fall würde man das Smartphone dann als stehend bezeichnen, wenn es eben auf diesen Noppen auf dem Tisch aufliegt.

Zu den Gläsern, Tellern usw. behaupte ich (kann es aber an nichts Weiterem festmachen), dass sie meistens Teil eines Assembles sind, d. h., es sind vorgesehene Positionen vorhanden. Ein Glas steht üblicherweise links oder rechts hinter dem Teller, Besteck seitlich davon. D. h., es existiert eine Aufstellung und entsprechend werden diese Objekte auf**gestellt.**

Comment: Servietten kann man durchaus aufstellen.

Comment: Nur gefaltete Servietten.

Comment: Und genau da (Achtung: deutsche Redewendung) "liegt der Hase im Pfeffer". Nur auf bestimmte Weise gefaltete Servietten werden auch gestellt: durch die spezielle Faltung wird ein Standfuß/-bein definiert und damit auch die "korrekte" Ausrichtung der Serviette im Raum. Erst dann wird unterschieden, ob etwas liegt oder steht.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the verb *stellen* means to put something standing up.

> Ich stelle das Buch auf den Tisch.

If you want to put the book flat on the table, you say:

> Ich lege das Buch auf den Tisch.

If someone asks you where it is and it is flat on the table, you say:

> Das Buch liegt auf dem Tisch.

If somebody asks you where it is and it is standing up on the table, you say:

> Das Buch steht auf dem Tisch.

To better determine whether to use *stellen*, *legen*, *stehen* or *liegen* is by reading German books.

Comment: Like http://german.stackexchange.com/users/9659/sempie said, it is related to the predefined alignment. Look at the context of the storing of books in a shelf: to perceive  it as "stehend" it has to be aligned in that way.